# Confusing "duplicate identifier" Typescript error message

Tags: typescript

Why am I getting this and many more errors of this kind? I am adding a link to the repo as well as key code snippets below. I think I have a basic misunderstanding of how the dependency and "include" chaining works.

```
csvproc(master)> tsc
node_modules/typescript/bin/lib.core.d.ts(83,5): error TS2300: Duplicate identifier 'configurable'.
node_modules/typescript/bin/lib.core.d.ts(84,5): error TS2300: Duplicate identifier 'enumerable'.
node_modules/typescript/bin/lib.core.d.ts(85,5): error TS2300: Duplicate identifier 'value'.
node_modules/typescript/bin/lib.core.d.ts(86,5): error TS2300: Duplicate identifier 'writable'.
```

[All code can be found here](https://github.com/pitosalas/typescript/tree/master/csvproc).

My tsconfig.json:

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "module": "commonjs",
        "noImplicitAny": false,
        "outDir": "built/",
        "sourceMap": true,
        "target": "es5"
    }
}
```

My tsd.json:

```
{
  "version": "v4",
  "repo": "borisyankov/DefinitelyTyped",
  "ref": "master",
  "path": "typings",
  "bundle": "typings/tsd.d.ts",
  "installed": {
    "node/node-0.10.d.ts": {
      "commit": "6387999eb899d0ba02d37dd8697647718caca230"
    },
    "should/should.d.ts": {
      "commit": "e1182d56ccb192379eade6055d9ba3fb6a0bacc4"
    }
  }
}
```

My tsd.d.ts:

```
{
  "version": "v4",
  "repo": "borisyankov/DefinitelyTyped",
  "ref": "master",
  "path": "typings",
  "bundle": "typings/tsd.d.ts",
  "installed": {
    "node/node-0.10.d.ts": {
      "commit": "6387999eb899d0ba02d37dd8697647718caca230"
    },
    "should/should.d.ts": {
      "commit": "e1182d56ccb192379eade6055d9ba3fb6a0bacc4"
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Your `tsd.d.ts` probably looks like a couple of reference tags, and not a JSON file.

Comment: Why do you need a `typings.json` AND a `tsd.d.ts`?

Comment: I put the solution here, you can see. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40404353/angularfire2-doesnt-work-after-released-to-beta-6/45404149#45404149

Answer (score 147, accepted):

This is because of the combination of two things:

- `tsconfig` not having any `files` section. From http://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/tsconfig-json.html

  > If no "files" property is present in a tsconfig.json, the compiler defaults to including all files in the containing directory and subdirectories. When a "files" property is specified, only those files are included.
- Including `typescript` as an npm dependency : `node_modules/typescript/` This means that all of `typescript` gets included .... there is an implicitly included `lib.d.ts` in your project anyways (http://basarat.gitbook.io/typescript/content/docs/types/lib.d.ts.html) and its conflicting with the one that ships with the NPM version of typescript.

## Fix

Either list `files` or `include` explicitly https://basarat.gitbook.io/typescript/project/compilation-context/files

Comment: Or install typescript globally instead?

Comment: Yeah I don't know why its there locally :) I assumed perhaps he needed some api from it (in hindsight ... its unlikely)

Comment: RyanCavanaugh yes, that was the problem; and @basarat, I'm not sophisticated yet, so it was just an oversight that I had it both locally and globally. Or in my defense, that doing that in the ruby world where I come from doesn't harm things, so that was my context :) Still the info you added to your response continues to complete the picture for me. So thanks. both of you!

Comment: Complete Gulp newbie here, but I've removed typescript from the node_modules folder, and installed it globally, but now the gulp task complains that it can't find the typescript module, and it's looking for it in the folder I've just removed. I'm guessing I've missed something, but I can't work out what.

Comment: Use `exclude` property

Comment: Even with that change inside tsconfig.js TSL keeps underling in red your "duplicate" objects... so I had to restart VSCode for TSL behavior update...

Comment: This did not fix my problem :( what are the files we need to exclude? If I have `@types/react` and `@types/react-router-dom` I get this error: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52323056/typescript-error-duplicate-identifier-librarymanagedattributes

Comment: Please note that if you use incremental builds, you should wipe your `.tsbuildinfo` files before trying to fix the problem. It took me a while to figure out that my problem was long solved, and I was only still getting this error because of the corrupted/outdated info in `.tsbuildinfo`.

Comment: certify that you don't have both @types/node and ts-node installed at the same time; It fixed for me to check my package.json and remove all old clutter

Comment: another possible fix is to add `"skipLibCheck": true` to `compilerOptions` of tsconfig.json

Comment: I got to a point where this was SO bad that I had to just create a new project and copy and paste the code inside. It worked which tells me installing something made this happen. I need to be more careful on what I install or uninstall from my project.

Answer (score 74):

**Update**: Version 1.0 of Typings changed the output structure and the below answer relates to pre 1.0 version.

If you are using Typings and exclude in your tsconfig.json, you may run into the issue of duplicate types and need something like the following:

```
{
  "exclude": [
    "typings/browser.d.ts",
    "typings/browser",
    "node_modules"
  ]
}
```

> To simplify integration with TypeScript, two files - typings/main.d.ts and typings/browser.d.ts - are generated which reference all the typings installed in the project only one of which can be used at a time.

So depending on which version you need, you should exclude (or include) the "browser" or the "main" type files, but not both, as this is where the duplicates come from.

[This Typings issue](https://github.com/typings/typings/issues/151) discusses it more.

Comment: Awesome man, this solves the issue with the duplicate identifier error from including [Typings](https://github.com/typings/typings) in your project :)

Comment: why not just exclude "typings"?  The typings are only for dev time right, not for run time?

Comment: This is defining where to find the types at compile time. If you exclude "typings" you can no longer find any types. There problem here is it is trying to compile and there are duplicate types. TypeScript is not a runtime, it transpiles your code to JavaScript.

Comment: In VS2017 I had to exclude "bin", "obj" in .NETCore2 MVC app

Comment: I had the same issue as OSP on this one. The obj folder had the TypeScript files in them, so they were showing up as duplicates. It caused problems the first time I built every time and then kept causing problems every time I built once I changed the build type.

Answer (score 34):

Problem was solved by simply:

1. Deleting the `node_modules` folder
2. Running `npm install` to get all packages with correct versions

In my case, the problem occurred after changing Git branches, where a new branch was using a different set of node modules. The old branch was using TypeScript v1.8, the new one v2.0

Comment: Yay this worked for me. I wasn't able to delete node_modules at first because it says it needs Administrator access to delete it. My user account has administrator access; the real issue was that I needed to close programs that were using the folder.

Comment: it causes me many issues with compilation

Comment: It worked for me. I just removed the *.lock file and install again.

Answer (score 29):

If you have installed typings separately in the typings folder add this to tsconfig.json:

```
{
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules",
    "typings"
  ]
}
```

Comment: I had a copy under /obj as well, which caused errors coming from "Typescript Virtual Projects". Adding "obj" to exclude fixed those.

Comment: This fully breaks my build sind the typings are missing.

Comment: Worked to my case, where I'm in a Cordova project. I had to exclude "platforms" folder also.

Answer (score 17):

You could also use the exclude option in tsconfig.json file like so:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es5",
    "module": "commonjs",
    "declaration": false,
    "noImplicitAny": false,
    "removeComments": true,
    "noLib": false,
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true
  },
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules"
  ]
}
```

Comment: I'having this exact same issue. This fix does not work for me. I'm using Typescrip 1.75. I posted [an issue in the Typescript Github repo](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/6489).

Comment: If you are using typings and not TSD you should use the solution proposed by @RationalDev

Answer (score 15):

I just ran into this problem. When I ran `npm start`, I got a bunch of duplicate identifier errors.

**SOLUTION:**

From the project root folder run:

```
rm -r typings
typings install
npm start
```

and everything works fine.

Comment: For me, I was switching from using `es6-shim` to using `core-js` for my polyfills, and this is the solution that would have worked. A less heavy-handed approach is to use `typings prune`.

Comment: Works for me. But guess there should be 'npm install' instead of 'typings install'

Comment: I have no `typings` folder :(

Answer (score 12):

Enabling skipLibCheck in tsconfig fixed it for me.

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "skipLibCheck": true /* Skip type checking all .d.ts files. */
  },
  "exclude": ["node_modules"],
  "include": ["./src/**/*.ts"]
}
```

Answer (score 4):

In my case I got the error as

> node_modules/@types/es6-promise/index.d.ts(11,15): error TS2300: Duplicate identifier 'Promise'.

And I had `@types/es6-promise` on my package.json but my `tsconfig` was already with `target: "es6"`. So I guess there was a conflict with `Promise` when compiling.

Removing `@types/es6-promise` from my `package.json` file solved the issue.

Answer (score 4):

Add "skipLibCheck": true to the "compilerOptions"

https://github.com/ionic-team/capacitor/issues/5436#issuecomment-1077942409

Comment: Sure, if you're aware of the implications of disabling type consistency checks for all your dependencies. This is not a good solution.

Answer (score 3):

Using **webpack** I came across same error, just in case excluding the `.d.ts` file in your **tsconfig.json** and node_modules solved my issue:

```
"exclude": [
    "node_modules",
    "typings/main",
    "typings/main.d.ts",
    "typings/index.d.ts"
]
```

Comment: I had this error with webpack too, just restarting the server fixed it.

Answer (score 3):

Adding `"typeRoots": ["node_modules/@types"],` to "compilerOptions" in tsconfig.json file worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

I had this issue caused by having an unexpected folder on disk (`jspm_packages`, no longer being used) which was not tracked by source control (and hidden from my IDE). This had a duplicate install of TypeScript in it, which caused the issues.

Bit of an edge case but leaving an answer here just in case someone else is hunting for this solution.

Comment: Similar to me. I renamed a typescript file in Visual Studio Code which caused an invisible (orphansed) .js file that no longer showed in the IDE but was showing the duplicate identifier error nonetheless.

Answer (score 1):

run the following command will fix this issue.

`npm install @types/node --save-dev`

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem and it turns out I had a a second node_modules folder in my project that wasn't supposed to be there :-(

Comment: There are some libraries that have node_modules inside their folders. when i was using node 4.6.0 it never created any problem, but with node 6.9.0 it suddenly is throwing that error.

Comment: Wonder what version this issue started with. I had the issue with node 5.6.0.

Answer (score 0):

I had this error, along with others, after I changed my tsconfig.json to target:"es2015", and module:"es2015".

The base (AngularJS2 quickstart) used `/// <reference path="../../typings/index.d.ts" />` in the main.ts file.  To solve this, I had to remove that line.

Answer (score 0):

we removed a lib folder from the website folder. this was created by a previous installation of typings. this became duplicate. When this was removed it worked!

Answer (score 0):

It can be because of having both typing and dependency in your node folder.
so first check what you have in your @types folder and if you have them in dependencies, remove the duplicate.
for me it was core.js

Answer (score 0):

remove this @types/express-validator from package.json file, then run npm install

[Read More](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@types/express-validator)

Author message:
This package has been deprecated
This is a stub types definition for express-validator (https://github.com/ctavan/express-validator). express-validator provides its own type definitions, so you don't need @types/express-validator installed!

Answer (score 0):

Closing the solution completely and rerunning the project solved my issue.

Comment: Or just recheck the typescript errors in the Typescript tab in IntelliJ

Answer (score 0):

**A (possible) solution for Angular**

In my case, when installing [@angularfire](https://github.com/angular/angularfire). It automatically imported `environment` from my environments file. Which gave the `Duplicate identifier 'environment'` error.

However, I already had this import in the same file, so that caused the duplicate identifier error.

It took me creating a new project and going step by step to find this error...

TL;DR: Check for duplicate imports in the file the error occurs.

Answer (score -2):

I ran into a similar problem. Simply moving my tsconfig.json from the root of my project up to a different scope helped. In my project, I moved tsconfig.json from the root up to wwwroot.