# LESS: No nested compile when save imported file in Web Essentials 2015

Tags: less, visual-studio-2015, web-essentials

I have a less file `main.less` that `@imports` other less files so they can all be compiled into a single `main.css` file.

With Web Essentials 2013, saving any of the imported files would trigger a compile of the `main.less` - which isn't happening with this extension.

Is there a configuration I'm missing?

Right now I use Alt-Shift-y as a workaround to force compile all the less files.

I don't want to go with the grunt solution, described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31345130/cant-compile-nested-less-files-with-web-compiler-2015)

Answer (score 0):

Do you have Web Workbench installed? That helped me, then it compiles automatically. https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/2b96d16a-c986-4501-8f97-8008f9db141a