# Using gulp to compile typescript can't find globally installed typescript package

Tags: typescript, gulp

I've been trying to set up a Gulp task in Visual Studio 2015 for a new Asp.Net 5 project, to compile my typescript in to javascript. I had initial issues with conflicts with the Typescript definition files I'd installed using tsd, but following the answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31322525/typescript-confusing-duplicate-identifier-error-message/31330272#comment55483062_31330272), I removed the Typescript node module from the project and installed it globally.

However, now the gulp task complains that it can't find the typescript module, and it's looking for it in the folder I've just removed from the project. I'm guessing I've missed something, but I can't work out what.

Update:

I've set an environment variable NODE_PATH to point to the global packages folder, but that's not made a difference. I'm guessing that the dependency that gulp-tsc has got to the typescript package isn't being redirected to the global package?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> but following the answer to this question, I removed the Typescript node module from the project and installed it globally.

Just install it locally and `exclude` (docs https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/tsconfig.json#examples) the node_modules folder