# Webstorm, TypeScript, Angular2, Transpiler, Duplicate Identifier error messages

Tags: typescript, duplicates, ecmascript-6, webstorm, angular

OS: **Windows Pro 10**
Webstorm: **ver 11.0.1**
AngularJS: **ver 2.0.0-alpha.46**

**WebStorm Settings**

1. Tools – File Watcher: **Babal**
2. Language & Frameworks – JavaScript:
   JavaScript language version: **ECMAScript 6**
3. Language & Frameworks – TypeScript:
   **Enable TypeScript Compiler (checked)**:
   **Use tsconfig.json (checked)**

**Project structure:**

```
- bin
- node_modules/angular2
- src/tsconfig.json
- package.json
```

**Package.json**

```
{
  "name": "TypeScriptHTMLApp2",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "dependencies": {
    "angular2": "2.0.0-alpha.46",
    "es6-shim": "^0.33.13",
    "systemjs": "0.19.6"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-preset-es2015": "^6.3.13"
  }
}
```

**tsconfig.json**

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es6",
    "module": "commonjs",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "removeComments": false,
    "noImplicitAny": false
  },
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules"
  ]
}
```

Note: node_modules folder in the webstorm project window, has also been set to 'exclude'.

So webstorm is throwing the following duplicate identifier error messages:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\JetBrains\WebStorm 11.0.1\plugins\JavaScriptLanguage\typescriptCompiler\external\lib.es6.d.ts
Error:(3841, 14) TS2300: Duplicate identifier 'PropertyKey'.
Error:(4034, 5) TS2300: Duplicate identifier 'EPSILON'.
Error:(4069, 5) TS2300: Duplicate identifier 'MAX_SAFE_INTEGER'.
Error:(4076, 5) TS2300: Duplicate identifier 'MIN_SAFE_INTEGER'.
Error:(4362, 5) TS2300: Duplicate identifier 'done'.
Error:(4363, 5) TS2300: Duplicate identifier 'value'.
Error:(4592, 5) TS2300: Duplicate identifier 'flags'.
Error:(4620, 5) TS2300: Duplicate identifier 'size'.
Error:(4630, 5) TS2300: Duplicate identifier 'prototype'.
Error:(4647, 5) TS2300: Duplicate identifier 'prototype'.
Error:(4659, 5) TS2300: Duplicate identifier 'size'.
Error:(4669, 5) TS2300: Duplicate identifier 'prototype'.
Error:(4685, 5) TS2300: Duplicate identifier 'prototype'.
Error:(5072, 5) TS2300: Duplicate identifier 'prototype'.
C:\Users\Theo\Documents\WebStorm\Projects\TypeScriptHTMLApp2\TypeScriptHTMLApp2\node_modules\angular2\typings\es6-shim\es6-shim.d.ts
Error:(6, 14) TS2300: Duplicate identifier 'PropertyKey'.
Error:(9, 5) TS2300: Duplicate identifier 'done'.
Error:(10, 5) TS2300: Duplicate identifier 'value'.
Error:(248, 5) TS2300: Duplicate identifier 'EPSILON'.
Error:(283, 5) TS2300: Duplicate identifier 'MAX_SAFE_INTEGER'.
Error:(290, 5) TS2300: Duplicate identifier 'MIN_SAFE_INTEGER'.
Error:(346, 5) TS2300: Duplicate identifier 'flags'.
Error:(498, 5) TS2300: Duplicate identifier 'prototype'.
Error:(561, 5) TS2300: Duplicate identifier 'size'.
Error:(570, 5) TS2300: Duplicate identifier 'prototype'.
Error:(581, 5) TS2300: Duplicate identifier 'size'.
Error:(590, 5) TS2300: Duplicate identifier 'prototype'.
Error:(605, 5) TS2300: Duplicate identifier 'prototype'.
Error:(619, 5) TS2300: Duplicate identifier 'prototype'.
```

How do I resolve this issue?

Many thanks in advance

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31322525/typescript-confusing-duplicate-identifier-error-message ... it's just a guess what the issue may be.

Comment: Are you using both Babel and Typescript?
Probably that's the mistake!
You not need Babel, just set "ES5" as target in your tsconfig

Comment: @Hitmands The issue has been resolved since I upgraded to webstorm 11.0.2  

Initially I thought the same thing, but it's a legitimate practice. Doing so my project generates, from the initial .ts files, .js, .js.map, compiled.js, and compiled.js.map files.  

See the following article for using both typescript and babel compilers:  

[link]http://dev.ivogabe.com/combine-typescript-with-babel  

And here's the initial document I used to setup webstorm with babel:  

[link] http://blog.jetbrains.com/webstorm/2015/05/ecmascript-6-in-webstorm-transpiling/#babelfilewatcher

Comment: Hey @TheoG, sincerely i prefer using IDE just as a platform for manage projects (coding, ecc...), but, for building process I use webpack, gulp and tools like these because I need to perform building even in deployment phases :)

Answer (score -2):

This happens when BOTH files are open in the editor. If you close one of the files, the error goes away...

Look at here: [Webstorm marks duplicate identifier error for variables from separate files](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/115000761564-Webstorm-marks-duplicate-identifier-error-for-variables-from-separate-files)

Comment: Unfortunately, it can also happen outside of that scope. One same symptom does not mean the issue is the same