# Cannot compile Ionic2 Cordova6 app on Visual Studio 2015

Tags: cordova, typescript, visual-studio-2015, visual-studio-cordova, ionic2

Following this [tutorial](https://github.com/Microsoft/cordova-docs/blob/981e054c2c08d199299b4e31a94014da7829c440/articles/getting-started/tutorial-ionic2.md) I created a working app, but after I updated to Cordova Tools 6 for Visual Studio I cannot compile anymore because a lot of duplicate identifiers. If I target ES5 instead of ES6 it works.
I'm using ionic CLI to 2.0.0-beta.17.

My *package.json*:

```
{
  "dependencies": {
    "angular2": "2.0.0-beta.2",
    "es6-promise": "3.0.2",
    "es6-shim": "0.33.13",
    "ionic-framework": "2.0.0-alpha.57",
    "ionicons": "3.0.0-alpha.3",
    "reflect-metadata": "0.1.2",
    "rxjs": "5.0.0-beta.0",
    "zone.js": "0.5.10"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "awesome-typescript-loader": "0.15.10",
    "strip-sourcemap-loader": "0.0.1",
    "typescript": "1.7.5"
  },
  "name": "firstaid",
  "description": "FirstAid: An Ionic project",
  "cordovaPlugins": [],
  "cordovaPlatforms": [
    {
      "platform": "android",
      "locator": "windows"
    }
  ]
}
```

My compile output:

```
------ Build started: Project: FirstAid, Configuration: Debug Android ------
Build started 16-Feb-16 17:50:33.
     1>
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\TypeScript\1.7\lib.es6.d.ts(3841,14): error TS2300: Build: Duplicate identifier 'PropertyKey'.
     1>
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\TypeScript\1.7\lib.es6.d.ts(4061,5): error TS2300: Build: Duplicate identifier 'EPSILON'.
     1>
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\TypeScript\1.7\lib.es6.d.ts(4096,5): error TS2300: Build: Duplicate identifier 'MAX_SAFE_INTEGER'.
     1>
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\TypeScript\1.7\lib.es6.d.ts(4103,5): error TS2300: Build: Duplicate identifier 'MIN_SAFE_INTEGER'.
     1>
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\TypeScript\1.7\lib.es6.d.ts(4389,5): error TS2300: Build: Duplicate identifier 'done'.
     1>
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\TypeScript\1.7\lib.es6.d.ts(4390,5): error TS2300: Build: Duplicate identifier 'value'.
     1>
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\TypeScript\1.7\lib.es6.d.ts(4619,5): error TS2300: Build: Duplicate identifier 'flags'.
     1>
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\TypeScript\1.7\lib.es6.d.ts(4647,5): error TS2300: Build: Duplicate identifier 'size'.
     1>
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\TypeScript\1.7\lib.es6.d.ts(4657,5): error TS2300: Build: Duplicate identifier 'prototype'.
     1>
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\TypeScript\1.7\lib.es6.d.ts(4674,5): error TS2300: Build: Duplicate identifier 'prototype'.
     1>
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\TypeScript\1.7\lib.es6.d.ts(4686,5): error TS2300: Build: Duplicate identifier 'size'.
     1>
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\TypeScript\1.7\lib.es6.d.ts(4696,5): error TS2300: Build: Duplicate identifier 'prototype'.
     1>
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\TypeScript\1.7\lib.es6.d.ts(4712,5): error TS2300: Build: Duplicate identifier 'prototype'.
     1>
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\TypeScript\1.7\lib.es6.d.ts(5099,5): error TS2300: Build: Duplicate identifier 'prototype'.
     1>
C:\app\a\FirstAid\FirstAid\node_modules\angular2\typings\es6-shim\es6-shim.d.ts(6,14): error TS2300: Build: Duplicate identifier 'PropertyKey'.
     1>
C:\app\a\FirstAid\FirstAid\node_modules\angular2\typings\es6-shim\es6-shim.d.ts(9,5): error TS2300: Build: Duplicate identifier 'done'.
     1>
C:\app\a\FirstAid\FirstAid\node_modules\angular2\typings\es6-shim\es6-shim.d.ts(10,5): error TS2300: Build: Duplicate identifier 'value'.
     1>
C:\app\a\FirstAid\FirstAid\node_modules\angular2\typings\es6-shim\es6-shim.d.ts(248,5): error TS2300: Build: Duplicate identifier 'EPSILON'.
     1>
C:\app\a\FirstAid\FirstAid\node_modules\angular2\typings\es6-shim\es6-shim.d.ts(283,5): error TS2300: Build: Duplicate identifier 'MAX_SAFE_INTEGER'.
     1>
C:\app\a\FirstAid\FirstAid\node_modules\angular2\typings\es6-shim\es6-shim.d.ts(290,5): error TS2300: Build: Duplicate identifier 'MIN_SAFE_INTEGER'.
     1>
C:\app\a\FirstAid\FirstAid\node_modules\angular2\typings\es6-shim\es6-shim.d.ts(346,5): error TS2300: Build: Duplicate identifier 'flags'.
     1>
C:\app\a\FirstAid\FirstAid\node_modules\angular2\typings\es6-shim\es6-shim.d.ts(498,5): error TS2300: Build: Duplicate identifier 'prototype'.
     1>
C:\app\a\FirstAid\FirstAid\node_modules\angular2\typings\es6-shim\es6-shim.d.ts(561,5): error TS2300: Build: Duplicate identifier 'size'.
     1>
C:\app\a\FirstAid\FirstAid\node_modules\angular2\typings\es6-shim\es6-shim.d.ts(570,5): error TS2300: Build: Duplicate identifier 'prototype'.
     1>
C:\app\a\FirstAid\FirstAid\node_modules\angular2\typings\es6-shim\es6-shim.d.ts(581,5): error TS2300: Build: Duplicate identifier 'size'.
     1>
C:\app\a\FirstAid\FirstAid\node_modules\angular2\typings\es6-shim\es6-shim.d.ts(590,5): error TS2300: Build: Duplicate identifier 'prototype'.
     1>
C:\app\a\FirstAid\FirstAid\node_modules\angular2\typings\es6-shim\es6-shim.d.ts(605,5): error TS2300: Build: Duplicate identifier 'prototype'.
     1>
C:\app\a\FirstAid\FirstAid\node_modules\angular2\typings\es6-shim\es6-shim.d.ts(619,5): error TS2300: Build: Duplicate identifier 'prototype'.

Build FAILED.

Time Elapsed 00:00:01.24
======== Build: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
```

My *tsconfig.json*

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es6",
    "module": "commonjs",
    "noEmitOnError": false,
    "rootDir": ".",
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "sourceMap": false,
    "inlineSourceMap": false,
    "inlineSources": false
  },
  "files": [
    "app/app.ts"
  ],
  "exclude": [
        "node_modules"
  ],
  "compileOnSave": false
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If this is the same issues as here: [Typescript, confusing "duplicate identifier" error message](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31322525/typescript-confusing-duplicate-identifier-error-message)

Then your problem is twofold.
1) There is a problem in your tsconfig.json, such as missing the files section (can you update your question with your tsconfig file?)
2) Typescript is installed twice, globally and locally, so TS is in the local node_modules folder at the root of your project.

Comment: I updated with my tsconfig.json, if I change target to "es5" it all works, but with "es6" I got the duplicated identifier errors...