# many Duplicate Identifier errors on testing type script application

Tags: node.js, testing, typescript, npm, gulp

searching the whole morning for a solution...

I use typescript on (node, npm, bower and gulp).
On gulp serve / gulp test I got hundreds of same error message:

```
src\app\main\common\dialogs\collections\collections.controller.ts(1,8): error TS2300: Duplicate identifier 'IDialogService'.
src\app\main\common\dialogs\createproject\createprojectdialog.controller.ts(1,8): error TS2300: Duplicate identifier 'ILogService'.
src\app\main\common\dialogs\datasheet\create\controller.ts(1,8): error TS2300: Duplicate identifier 'IDialogService'.
src\app\main\common\dialogs\decisor\controller.ts(1,8): error TS2300: Duplicate identifier 'IDialogService'.
```

my Compiler Options:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "module": "commonjs",
    "target": "es5",
    "sourceMap": true
  },
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules"
  ]
}
```

Anyone who can give me a hint... ?

regards *n00n*

Comment: Possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31322525/typescript-confusing-duplicate-identifier-error-message

Comment: no, I found your link before, but it could not help to solve my problem...

Answer (score 0):

I see lots of `Duplicate identifier 'IDialogService'.` I suspect the error is *genuine* and you are doing something like :

```
 interface Something {
   IDialogService: Foo;
 }
```

*multiple times in your codebase*. You should only have this *once*.

Comment: Yes, there are many files importing the IDialogService. I do not know if I can import it once...

Comment: You can `import` it as many times as you want. But you must not define it more than once

Answer (score 0):

solved like this

instead of 
import foo as library.foo;
function .. (..., foo, ... )

I used: 
function .. (..., library.foo, ... )