# Angular2 beta 17 - Duplicate identifier error

Tags: node.js, express, angular, mean

Angular2 - duplicate identifier error

```
M:/workspace/Angular2StartKit/node_modules/angular2/typings/browser.d.ts(6,14): error TS2300:     Duplicate identifier 'PromiseConstructor'.
M:/workspace/Angular2StartKit/node_modules/angular2/typings/es6-collections/es6-collections.d.    ts(22,5): error TS2300: Duplicate identifier 'done'.
M:/workspace/Angular2StartKit/node_modules/angular2/typings/es6-collections/es6-collections.d.    ts(23,5): error TS2300: Duplicate identifier 'value'.
M:/workspace/Angular2StartKit/node_modules/angular2/typings/es6-collections/es6-collections.d.    ts(46,5): error TS2300: Duplicate identifier 'size'.
M:/workspace/Angular2StartKit/node_modules/angular2/typings/es6-collections/es6-collections.d.    ts(52,5): error TS2300: Duplicate identifier 'prototype'.
M:/workspace/Angular2StartKit/node_modules/angular2/typings/es6-collections/es6-collections.d.    ts(66,5): error TS2300: Duplicate identifier 'size'.
M:/workspace/Angular2StartKit/node_modules/angular2/typings/es6-collections/es6-collections.d.    ts(72,5): error TS2300: Duplicate identifier 'prototype'.
M:/workspace/Angular2StartKit/node_modules/angular2/typings/es6-collections/es6-collections.d.    ts(88,5): error TS2300: Duplicate identifier 'prototype'.
M:/workspace/Angular2StartKit/node_modules/angular2/typings/es6-collections/es6-collections.d.    ts(103,5): error TS2300: Duplicate identifier 'prototype'.
M:/workspace/Angular2StartKit/node_modules/angular2/typings/es6-promise/es6-promise.d.ts(11,15):     error TS2300: Duplicate identifier 'Promise'.
M:/workspace/Angular2StartKit/node_modules/angular2/typings/es6-promise/es6-promise.d.ts(42,16):     error TS2300: Duplicate identifier 'Promise'.
__lib.d.ts(565,5): error TS2300: Duplicate identifier 'done'.
__lib.d.ts(566,5): error TS2300: Duplicate identifier 'value'.
__lib.d.ts(823,5): error TS2300: Duplicate identifier 'size'.
__lib.d.ts(833,5): error TS2300: Duplicate identifier 'prototype'.
__lib.d.ts(849,5): error TS2300: Duplicate identifier 'prototype'.
__lib.d.ts(861,5): error TS2300: Duplicate identifier 'size'.
__lib.d.ts(871,5): error TS2300: Duplicate identifier 'prototype'.
__lib.d.ts(886,5): error TS2300: Duplicate identifier 'prototype'.
__lib.d.ts(1257,11): error TS2300: Duplicate identifier 'Promise'.
__lib.d.ts(1278,11): error TS2300: Duplicate identifier 'PromiseConstructor'.
__lib.d.ts(1347,13): error TS2300: Duplicate identifier 'Promise'.
```

I have exculded the es6 files that the compiler is complaining about, but i am not sure if it is getting excluded for sure as the compiler is still complaining

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "ES6",
    "module": "system",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "removeComments": false,
    "noImplicitAny": false
  },

  "exclude": [
    "node_modules",
    "typings/es6-promise/es6-promise.d.ts",    
    "typings/es6-collections/es6-collections.d.ts",
    "dist"    
  ] 

}
```

I have also included the followin the bootstarp.js file after doing somereaserch online

```
///<reference path="../../node_modules/angular2/typings/browser.d.ts"/>
```

Any idea what's wrong here ?

Comment: Probably helpful, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31322525/typescript-confusing-duplicate-identifier-error-message

Comment: I deleted the conflicting files to make it work .. not the right approach, but had to move forward.

Answer (score 1):

Remove `///<reference path="../../node_modules/angular2/typings/browser.d.ts"/>`

in the exclude array of tsconfig.json
add the following

```
typings/browser.d.ts,
typings/browser
```