# Typings globals showing error + Angular 2 + Webpack

Tags: typescript, angular, npm, webpack, typing

I am using angular 2 with webpack and setup my project when I ran webpack watcher its given me `Duplicate identifier` errors:

```
ERROR in [default] /angular/typings/globals/node/index.d.ts:370:8 Duplicate identifier 'unescape'.
ERROR in [default] /angular/typings/globals/node/index.d.ts:371:8 Duplicate identifier 'gc'.
ERROR in [default] /angular/typings/globals/node/index.d.ts:372:8 Duplicate identifier 'v8debug'.
ERROR in [default] /angular/typings/globals/node/index.d.ts:446:25 Duplicate identifier 'Buffer'.
```

Below is my typings.json file:

```
{
  "name": "angular2",
  "version": false,
  "dependencies": {},
  "globalDependencies": {
    "es6-collections": "registry:dt/es6-collections#0.5.1+20160316155526",
    "es6-promise": "registry:dt/es6-promise#0.0.0+20160423074304",
    "node": "registry:dt/node#4.0.0+20160423143914"
  }
}
```

Comment: it might be some of the vendors are using the same dependencies

Comment: So how I can find it if they are? and how I can solve this issue?

Comment: try this one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31322525/typescript-confusing-duplicate-identifier-error-message

Answer (score 0):

You don't need tomanually add `node` typings.