# Excluding node_modules directory from tsconfig still being compiled

Tags: typescript, typescript1.8

I'm getting a number of TS2300 duplicate identifier errors when targetting ES6.

```
node_modules/typescript/lib/lib.es6.d.ts(17,14): error TS2300: Duplicate identifier 'PropertyKey'.              
node_modules/typescript/lib/lib.es6.d.ts(26,5): error TS2300: Duplicate identifier '[Symbol.toStringTag]'.     
node_modules/typescript/lib/lib.es6.d.ts(33,5): error TS2300: Duplicate identifier 'prototype'.               
node_modules/typescript/lib/lib.es6.d.ts(61,5): error TS2300: Duplicate identifier 'hasInstance'.
```

Here is my `tsconfig.json`.

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
        "experimentalDecorators": true,
        "module": "commonjs",
        "moduleResolution": "node",
        "noImplicitAny": false,
        "sourceMap": true,
        "target": "es6",
        "suppressImplicitAnyIndexErrors": true
    },
    "exclude": [
        "node_modules"
    ]
}
```

I'm not sure why the compiler is still throwing errors about anything in the `node_modules` directory when it's being excluded. I followed the suggestions from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31322525/typescript-confusing-duplicate-identifier-error-message) and the same errors still occur.

FWIW I'm compiling using this command.

```
./node_modules/.bin/tsc -p ./src
```

This appears to work using v2 beta. But it'd be nice to know why it fails using v1.8. I can't find any reported bugs on GitHub.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1):

> What am I missing?

Similar structures no longer error in 2.0. Used to in 1.8. That is what is fixing the error.

Comment: Does that mean that it isn't possible to target ES6 using the current stable TypeScript compiler?

Comment: @onetwothree FWIW, TypeScript 2.0 is now released.