# TypeScript error: Duplicate identifier 'LibraryManagedAttributes'

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

> Failed to compile.
>
> /moonholdings.io/node_modules/@types/react-dom/node_modules/@types/react/index.d.ts
> (2312,14): Duplicate identifier 'LibraryManagedAttributes'.

Not sure why I'm getting this.

I've downgraded my `"@types/node"` from 10 to 8 and that didn't work.
Also tried `"@types/node": "^9.6.7"`

My Repo: https://github.com/Futuratum/moonholdings.io

My package.json

```
{
  "name": "moonholdings.io",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "build-css": "node-sass-chokidar src/ -o src/ --source-map",
    "watch-css": "npm run build-css && node-sass-chokidar src/ -o src/ --watch --recursive --source-map",
    "start": "react-scripts-ts start",
    "build": "react-scripts-ts build",
    "test": "react-scripts-ts test --env=jsdom",
    "eject": "react-scripts-ts eject"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@types/react": "^16.4.14",
    "@types/react-redux": "^6.0.9",
    "node-sass-chokidar": "^1.3.3",
    "react": "^16.5.0",
    "react-dom": "^16.5.0",
    "react-redux": "^5.0.7",
    "react-router-dom": "^4.3.1",
    "react-scripts-ts": "2.17.0",
    "redux-thunk": "^2.3.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/jest": "^23.3.2",
    "@types/node": "^8.10.29",
    "@types/react-dom": "^16.0.7",
    "typescript": "^3.0.3"
  }
}
```

Here is my tsconfig

```
    {
  "compilerOptions": {
    "traceResolution": false,
    "strictNullChecks": true,
    "noImplicitAny": true,
    "module": "esnext",
    "target": "es5",
    "lib": [
      "es2015",
      "es2017",
      "es6",
      "es7",
      "es5",
      "dom"
    ],
    "jsx": "react",
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "baseUrl": "./src",
    "noUnusedLocals": true,
    "noUnusedParameters": false,
    "noImplicitAny": false,
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "importHelpers": true,
    "strictFunctionTypes": false
  },
  "include": [
    "src/**/*",
    "webpack/**/*"
  ],
  "files": [
    "core.ts",
    "sys.ts",
    "types.ts",
    "tsc.ts",
    "registerServiceWorker.ts",
    "src/registerServiceWorker.ts",
    "src/setupTests.ts"
  ],
  "exclude": [
    "typings/browser.d.ts",
    "typings/browser",
    "typings",
    "node_modules",
    "build",
    "scripts",
    "acceptance-tests",
    "webpack",
    "jest"
  ]
}
```

Comment: So now you have `node_modules/@types/react-dom/node_modules/@types/react/index.d.ts` and `node_modules/@types/react/index.d.ts`? I think your project type dependencies must match your transitive types dependencies.

Comment: @Leon Gaban https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31322525/confusing-duplicate-identifier-typescript-error-message

Comment: @zerkms yes I have types for both

Comment: @zerkms Ok so I removed the React types, and now getting other strange errors....

Comment: Also the answers in that question haven't helped so far :( but still digging in.

Comment: What are those new errors now?

Comment: A very similar issue was raised on GitHub https://github.com/ant-design/ant-design/issues/11697

Comment: I suddenly have the same issue. Still no clue how to solve it or where it comes from.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm still not sure what caused that bug, however I've checked out a much earlier version of my app, where it was stable. So going to continue work from there.

Here is the working package.json

```
{
  "name": "moonholdings.io",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts-ts start",
    "build": "react-scripts-ts build",
    "test": "react-scripts-ts test --env=jsdom",
    "eject": "react-scripts-ts eject"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@types/jest": "^23.3.1",
    "@types/node": "^10.9.4",
    "@types/react": "^16.4.13",
    "@types/react-dom": "^16.0.7",
    "react": "^16.4.2",
    "react-dom": "^16.4.2",
    "react-ts-with-scss": "2.1.0",
    "typescript": "^3.0.3"
  },
  "devDependencies": {}
}
```

Comment: That didn't solve the problem for me. I would guess if you delete your `node_modules` folder and do a fresh `yarn install` and `yarn build` the error will reappear. I found another workaround: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52399839/typescript-duplicate-identifier-librarymanagedattributes

Comment: Why did you accept your own answer? Its not a real solution.

Answer (score 9):

You may find that the duplicates are located in `node_modules/@types/react` and `node_modules/types/react-dom/@types/react` or a similar set-up, in which one of the packages has a nested dependency on the other.

Uninstalling and reinstalling @types/react-dom and @types/react together is what fixed it for me.

```
yarn remove @types/react-dom @types/react


yarn add -D @types/react-dom @types/react
```

Comment: Thank you so much! Tried so many different tricks form here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52399839/duplicate-identifier-librarymanagedattributes but this worked perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error.
I upgraded [@types/react](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@types/react) and [@types/react-dom](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@types/react-dom) to their latest versions in `package.json` and it fixed my error.

Comment: is it not because typescript code is only for development. Once it is transpiled for deployment it is javascript so types are no longer neccessary? Are types not always menat to be dev deps

Comment: types should only be in your devDeps

Comment: Thanks @shallow.alchemy to clarify this. It makes sense, I guess, since types don't matter at runtime anymore. I'll keep an eye out for this if I'll pick up TS again