# error TS2300: Duplicate identifier 'A'. but there is only one class declaration of A

Tags: typescript

Here is a very simple typescript code in a file `test.ts`

```
// Testing
//
class A {
   private field1;
   config;
    constructor() {
            this.field1 = undefined;
            this.config = undefined;
    }
};

function func() {
    const config = new A();
    return { config };
};

const { config: A } = func();
```

I used `npx tsc test.ts` to compile the above, and I got these error messages

```
test.ts(3,7): error TS2300: Duplicate identifier 'A'.
test.ts(17,17): error TS2300: Duplicate identifier 'A'.
```

What is wrong with the code? Where does the duplicate come from?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31322525/confusing-duplicate-identifier-typescript-error-message

Comment: Not applicable. I explicitly provided a file to tsc

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`const { config: A } = func();`

This line is saying you expect `func()` to return an object with a `config` property, and you're trying to assign the value of that to a new const named `A`, but you've already defined `A` as a class

Comment: Thx! I thought I can use `:A` there is to specify the data type of the variable `config`. So how can I restrict the type of `config`?

Comment: config should be automatically implied.
`const { config } = func();` should automatically make config of type A. But if you want explicit state the type, you'd have to do:

let config: A;
({ config } = func());

Comment: Awesome! It's exactly what I am looking for!