# Why is Typescript giving "Duplicate Identifier" error

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I am getting multiple `Duplicate identifier` and `Subsequent property declarations must have the same type.` errors when I run `yarn check-types` in my project.

package.json:

```
{
  "scripts": {
    "start": "webpack-dev-server --mode development --hot",
    "build": "webpack --mode production",
    "check-types": "tsc"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "react": "^16.12.0",
    "react-dom": "^16.12.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.8.3",
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties": "^7.8.3",
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-object-rest-spread": "^7.8.3",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.8.3",
    "@babel/preset-react": "^7.8.3",
    "@babel/preset-typescript": "^7.8.3",
    "@hot-loader/react-dom": "^16.11.0",
    "@types/react": "^16.9.17",
    "@types/react-dom": "^16.9.4",
    "babel-loader": "^8.0.6",
    "html-webpack-plugin": "^3.2.0",
    "react-hot-loader": "^4.12.18",
    "typescript": "^3.7.5",
    "webpack": "^4.41.5",
    "webpack-cli": "^3.3.10",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^3.10.1"
  }
}
```

tsconfig.json

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "target": "ESNext",
        "strictNullChecks": true,
        "moduleResolution": "node",
        "allowJs": true,
        "noEmit": true,
        "strict": true,
        "esModuleInterop": true,
        "jsx": "react",
        "lib": [
            "es2015",
            "dom.iterable",
            "es2016.array.include",
            "es2017.object",
            "dom"
        ],
        "module": "es6",
        "removeComments": true,
        "alwaysStrict": true,
        "allowUnreachableCode": false,
        "noImplicitAny": true,
        "noImplicitThis": true,
        "noUnusedLocals": true,
        "noUnusedParameters": true,
        "noImplicitReturns": true,
        "noFallthroughCasesInSwitch": true,
        "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
        "importHelpers": true
    },
    "include": [
        "src/**/*"
    ],
    "exclude": [
        "node_modules",
        "dist"
    ]
}
```

example errors:

```
node_modules/@types/react-native/globals.d.ts:40:15 - error TS2300: Duplicate identifier 'FormData'.

40 declare class FormData {
                 ~~~~~~~~

  node_modules/typescript/lib/lib.dom.d.ts:5710:11
    5710 interface FormData {
                   ~~~~~~~~
    'FormData' was also declared here.
  node_modules/typescript/lib/lib.dom.d.ts:5720:13
    5720 declare var FormData: {
                     ~~~~~~~~
    and here.
  node_modules/typescript/lib/lib.dom.iterable.d.ts:84:11
    84 interface FormData {
                 ~~~~~~~~
    and here.

node_modules/@types/react-native/globals.d.ts:85:5 - error TS2717: Subsequent property declarations must have the same type.  Property 'body' must be of type 'string | ArrayBuffer | ArrayBufferView | Blob | FormData | URLSearchParams | ReadableStream<Uint8Array> | null | undefined', but here has type 'string | ArrayBuffer | DataView | Int8Array | Uint8Array | Uint8ClampedArray | Int16Array | ... 8 more ... | undefined'.

85     body?: BodyInit_;
       ~~~~

  node_modules/typescript/lib/lib.dom.d.ts:1553:5
    1553     body?: BodyInit | null;
             ~~~~
    'body' was also declared here.

node_modules/@types/react-native/globals.d.ts:111:14 - error TS2300: Duplicate identifier 'RequestInfo'.

111 declare type RequestInfo = Request | string;
                 ~~~~~~~~~~~

  node_modules/typescript/lib/lib.dom.d.ts:20034:6
    20034 type RequestInfo = Request | string;
               ~~~~~~~~~~~
    'RequestInfo' was also declared here.

node_modules/@types/react-native/globals.d.ts:130:13 - error TS2403: Subsequent variable declarations must have the same type.  Variable 'Response' must be of type '{ new (body?: string | ArrayBuffer | ArrayBufferView | Blob | FormData | URLSearchParams | ReadableStream<Uint8Array> | null | undefined, init?: ResponseInit | undefined): Response; prototype: Response; error(): Response; redirect(url: string, status?: number | undefined): Response; }', but here has type '{ new (body?: string | ArrayBuffer | DataView | Int8Array | Uint8Array | Uint8ClampedArray | Int16Array | ... 8 more ... | undefined, init?: ResponseInit | undefined): Response; prototype: Response; error: () => Response; redirect: (url: string, status?: number | undefined) => Response; }'.

130 declare var Response: {
                ~~~~~~~~

  node_modules/typescript/lib/lib.dom.d.ts:12875:13
    12875 declare var Response: {
                      ~~~~~~~~
    'Response' was also declared here.

node_modules/@types/react-native/globals.d.ts:206:5 - error TS2717: Subsequent property declarations must have the same type.  Property 'abort' must be of type 'ProgressEvent<XMLHttpRequestEventTarget>', but here has type 'ProgressEvent<EventTarget>'.

206     abort: ProgressEvent;
        ~~~~~

  node_modules/typescript/lib/lib.dom.d.ts:19004:5
    19004     "abort": ProgressEvent<XMLHttpRequestEventTarget>;
              ~~~~~~~
    'abort' was also declared here.

node_modules/@types/react-native/globals.d.ts:207:5 - error TS2717: Subsequent property declarations must have the same type.  Property 'error' must be of type 'ProgressEvent<XMLHttpRequestEventTarget>', but here has type 'ProgressEvent<EventTarget>'.

207     error: ProgressEvent;
        ~~~~~

  node_modules/typescript/lib/lib.dom.d.ts:19005:5
    19005     "error": ProgressEvent<XMLHttpRequestEventTarget>;
              ~~~~~~~
    'error' was also declared here.

node_modules/@types/react-native/globals.d.ts:208:5 - error TS2717: Subsequent property declarations must have the same type.  Property 'load' must be of type 'ProgressEvent<XMLHttpRequestEventTarget>', but here has type 'ProgressEvent<EventTarget>'.

208     load: ProgressEvent;
        ~~~~

  node_modules/typescript/lib/lib.dom.d.ts:19006:5
    19006     "load": ProgressEvent<XMLHttpRequestEventTarget>;
              ~~~~~~
    'load' was also declared here.

node_modules/@types/react-native/globals.d.ts:209:5 - error TS2717: Subsequent property declarations must have the same type.  Property 'loadend' must be of type 'ProgressEvent<XMLHttpRequestEventTarget>', but here has type 'ProgressEvent<EventTarget>'.

209     loadend: ProgressEvent;
        ~~~~~~~

  node_modules/typescript/lib/lib.dom.d.ts:19007:5
    19007     "loadend": ProgressEvent<XMLHttpRequestEventTarget>;
              ~~~~~~~~~
    'loadend' was also declared here.

node_modules/@types/react-native/globals.d.ts:210:5 - error TS2717: Subsequent property declarations must have the same type.  Property 'loadstart' must be of type 'ProgressEvent<XMLHttpRequestEventTarget>', but here has type 'ProgressEvent<EventTarget>'.

210     loadstart: ProgressEvent;
        ~~~~~~~~~

  node_modules/typescript/lib/lib.dom.d.ts:19008:5
    19008     "loadstart": ProgressEvent<XMLHttpRequestEventTarget>;
              ~~~~~~~~~~~
    'loadstart' was also declared here.

node_modules/@types/react-native/globals.d.ts:211:5 - error TS2717: Subsequent property declarations must have the same type.  Property 'progress' must be of type 'ProgressEvent<XMLHttpRequestEventTarget>', but here has type 'ProgressEvent<EventTarget>'.

211     progress: ProgressEvent;
        ~~~~~~~~

  node_modules/typescript/lib/lib.dom.d.ts:19009:5
    19009     "progress": ProgressEvent<XMLHttpRequestEventTarget>;
              ~~~~~~~~~~
    'progress' was also declared here.

node_modules/@types/react-native/globals.d.ts:212:5 - error TS2717: Subsequent property declarations must have the same type.  Property 'timeout' must be of type 'ProgressEvent<XMLHttpRequestEventTarget>', but here has type 'ProgressEvent<EventTarget>'.

212     timeout: ProgressEvent;
        ~~~~~~~

  node_modules/typescript/lib/lib.dom.d.ts:19010:5
    19010     "timeout": ProgressEvent<XMLHttpRequestEventTarget>;
              ~~~~~~~~~
    'timeout' was also declared here.

node_modules/@types/react-native/globals.d.ts:253:14 - error TS2300: Duplicate identifier 'XMLHttpRequestResponseType'.

253 declare type XMLHttpRequestResponseType = '' | 'arraybuffer' | 'blob' | 'document' | 'json' | 'text';
                 ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

  node_modules/typescript/lib/lib.dom.d.ts:20227:6
    20227 type XMLHttpRequestResponseType = "" | "arraybuffer" | "blob" | "document" | "json" | "text";
               ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    'XMLHttpRequestResponseType' was also declared here.

node_modules/@types/react-native/globals.d.ts:258:15 - error TS2300: Duplicate identifier 'URLSearchParams'.

258 declare class URLSearchParams {
                  ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

  node_modules/typescript/lib/lib.dom.d.ts:16123:11
    16123 interface URLSearchParams {
                    ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    'URLSearchParams' was also declared here.
  node_modules/typescript/lib/lib.dom.d.ts:16156:13
    16156 declare var URLSearchParams: {
                      ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    and here.
  node_modules/typescript/lib/lib.dom.iterable.d.ts:263:11
    263 interface URLSearchParams {
                  ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    and here.

node_modules/@types/react-native/globals.d.ts:291:5 - error TS2717: Subsequent property declarations must have the same type.  Property 'onopen' must be of type '((this: WebSocket, ev: Event) => any) | null', but here has type '(() => void) | null'.
```

Please note that I have gone through the solutions for [the stack overflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31322525/2407971) and included `include` and `exclude` in `tsconfig.json` as suggested in the most upvoted answer. But its not working for me.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The TypeScript compiler is finding type conflicts in your dependencies. One method of resolving this complaint is to include `skipLibCheck: true` in your `tsconfig.json`'s `compilerOptions`.

Comment: Thanks a lot @Daniel. Just a typo `skipLibChecks` will be `skipLibCheck`