# Issues with TypeScript after compilation to JavaScript - "Duplicate identifier error"

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, visual-studio, npm

In VSCode, I am working with TypeScript and experiencing an issue when I compile to JavaScript whereby the IDE will complain that certain elements - classes, variables etc. - are duplicates. This is because they exist in the TypeScript file and the JavaScript file that is created as a result.

I imagine this is a fairly common problem, but to clarify a couple of things:

1. This does not appear to prevent TypeScript compilation
2. This only occurs when the .js file is *open* in the IDE (VSCode)

Below is an image showing what I mean:

[image: Duplicate identifier error]

I am not very experienced in working with npm or the command line, so I'm not sure if I've inadvertently enabled this behaviour or missed something out - it is clearly undesirable though, so I was wondering if anyone can think what might be causing the problem? For a start, is this more likely to be a VSCode problem or a TypeScript problem?

I have looked at a few similar questions on SO - e.g. [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31322525/confusing-duplicate-identifier-typescript-error-message), but none seem to be experiencing the exact same issue as me.

Many thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe you have both typescript and javascript in the same folder somehow. Can you share your tsconfig file? Important this to notice is `outdir` that will ensure that compiled files are not kept at the same destination.

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {

    "target": "es6",                          /* Specify ECMAScript target version: 'ES3' (default), 'ES5', 'ES2015', 'ES2016', 'ES2017', 'ES2018', 'ES2019', 'ES2020', or 'ESNEXT'. */
    "module": "commonjs",                     /* Specify module code generation: 'none', 'commonjs', 'amd', 'system', 'umd', 'es2015', 'es2020', or 'ESNext'. */
    "sourceMap": true,                     /* Generates corresponding '.map' file. */
    "outDir": "dist",                        /* Redirect output structure to the directory. */

    "strict": true,                           /* Enable all strict type-checking options. */


    "moduleResolution": "node",            /* Specify module resolution strategy: 'node' (Node.js) or 'classic' (TypeScript pre-1.6). */
    "esModuleInterop": true,                  /* Enables emit interoperability between CommonJS and ES Modules via creation of namespace objects for all imports. Implies 'allowSyntheticDefaultImports'. */



    "skipLibCheck": true,                     /* Skip type checking of declaration files. */
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true  /* Disallow inconsistently-cased references to the same file. */
  }
}
```

Package.json, this will allow you to run npm commands like npm start....

```json
{
  "name": "learning_ts",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "dist/target_group.js",
  "scripts": {
    "debug": "tsc && node --nolazy dist/target_group.js",
    "start": "tsc && node dist/target_group.js",
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "@types/node": "^14.11.1",
    "aws-sdk": "^2.756.0",
    "dotenv": "^8.2.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "tslint": "^5.12.1",
    "typescript": "^3.3.3"
  }
}
```

Comment: Hi Shubham, interestingly I do not appear to have a tsconfig file in the root folder - is this possible? Where might I find it?

Comment: you may have to create it. I will edit my answer and copy both package.json and tsconfig. Change that based on your need.

Comment: Ignore previous message if you saw it - I thought I had fixed the problem but it persists.

Here is my package.json file:

`{
  "name": "ts-sandbox",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
    "comp": "tsc --outDir js sandbox.ts"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "eslint": "^7.9.0",
    "typescript": "^4.0.3"
  }
}`

Comment: Creating a tsconfig file seems to have fixed it, yes. Thanks!